# Can't set up the path to a DLL on a server because not allowed to create folder called .NETFramework

Tags: .net

I developed a program on a 64-bit machine using .NET 4. It references the DLLs shown in the picture below. I am trying to deploy the program to a 32-bit server. Because the server is 32-bit, we need to create the directory structure leading to the DLL (I can't change this structure, the same program is deployed on 64-bit machines so the path needs to stay consistent). But when I try to create a folder "...\Microsoft\Framework \ .NETFramework" Windows Server says that "You must type a file name." It won't allow me to create a folder with a period at the start. How can I make a path like this? How can I start a folder name with a period? The SA recently installed .NET 4 on this server, but this path was not created.

[image]

**update** Maybe something went wrong with the install? When I go to look into the GAC (C\Windows\Assembly) I don't see the .net 4 DLLs in there. If I get the .NET 4 DLLs in there correctly then everything should "just work," correct?

[image]

Comment: Typically, for an 100% managed app you would just build for `Any CPU` and get on with your life. Then the correct references would be used no matter on what platform.

Comment: As per Reed's answer these assemblies should be in the GAC, assuming that v4.0 of the .NET Framework has been installed. To answer the question about creating a folder that with a name that begins with ".", try the md command via Command Prompt.

Answer (score 2):

> It references the DLLs shown in the picture below. I am trying to deploy the program to a 32-bit server. Because the server is 32-bit, we need to create the directory structure leading to the DLL (I can't change this structure, the same program is deployed on 64-bit machines so the path needs to stay consistent).

Any DLL installed as part of the .NET Framework itself should be in the GAC.  You shouldn't need to create this path, or worry about the path at all - just reference the DLL *from the GAC* and not by an absolute path and make sure that you're using 32bit versions of any dependencies, and it should "just work".

Comment: +1. Don't forget to mention that it should be build for `Any CPU` and not a specific platform. Or if multiple build targets, deploy the correct one.

Comment: @thecoon Or built specifically targetting x86 (that works as well, on both platforms)

Comment: Right. Since both x86 and x64 framework assemblies are installed anyway.

Comment: @ReedCopsey I added an update. Am I interpreting what I see in the GAC correctly? It looks like it only has system.dll v2 and v1. My application will look in this location for system.dll v4 and the other DLLs, right?

Comment: @akh2103 That's how it looks even with .NET 4.  The version there isn't the framework version, it's the assembly version...

Comment: @ReedCopsey the SA installed .NET 4. These should be added the GAC automatically if the install runs properly, correct?

Comment: @akh2103 Yes.  Make sure they installed the full framework, and not the client profile.. That could be the issue, maybe?

Comment: @ReedCopsey he says he installed the client profile. Do you have a link to the whole framework so we can install the right one? Thank you!